# Can't send emails to custom domains (non-gmail/hotmail emails) using Mailgun

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, mailgun

I am sending out confirmation (and other emails) when users sign up. The problem is that when I send to addresses that are not gmail or hotmail or any of the larger email services, it throws me an error in the email header.

```
{
  "severity": "permanent",
  "tags": [],
  "delivery-status": {
    "tls": false,
    "mx-host": "mxer.customdomain.com",
    "code": 553,
    "description": null,
    "session-seconds": 6.566637992858887,
    "message": "553 5.1.8 <user@customdomain.com>... Domain of sender address bounce+e06614.0f9698-user=customdomain.com@mg.mydomain.com does not exist",
    "certificate-verified": false
  },
  "envelope": {
    "transport": "smtp",
    "sender": "accounts@mydomain.com",
    "sending-ip": "123.45.678.900",
    "targets": "user@customdomain.com"
  },
  "recipient-domain": "customdomain.com",
  "id": "AbCDeFGhiJk_lMn",
  "campaigns": [],
  "reason": "generic",
  "user-variables": {},
  "flags": {
    "is-routed": null,
    "is-authenticated": true,
    "is-system-test": false,
    "is-test-mode": false
  },
  "log-level": "error",
  "timestamp": 1456123374.411238,
  "message": {
    "headers": {
      "to": "First Last <user@customdomain.com>",
      "message-id": "56caade72ed26_***********9@6e5120c5-0d27-4491-a430-1a2dc4e6b862.mail",
      "from": "Team Accounts <accounts@mydomain.com>",
      "subject": "Confirmation instructions"
    },
    "attachments": [],
    "recipients": [
      "user@customdomain.com"
    ],
    "size": 1143
  },
  "recipient": "user@customdomain.com",
  "event": "failed"
}
```

Did I set my headers wrongly or is there a configuration I need to set up before I can send emails to custom domains?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that for some email services, it requires a valid "receive" MX record for your domain/subdomain (for Mailgun it was `mg.mydomain.com`) to verify the identity of the sender. I added the MX records

```
10 mxa.mailgun.org
10 mxb.mailgun.org
```

for `mg.mydomain.com` and it seemed to have worked.